# Text Recognization :: Google ML Kit does not recognizes seven segment display numbers and decimals

Tags: android, firebase, text-recognition, firebase-mlkit, seven-segment-display

I am trying to get numbers from seven segment display image using ML kit but it does not recognizes the numbers or decimals from the image. It recognizes the normal text and number from image but not from the seven segment display image. Please refer below for my findings.

1.Works fine with normal text and numbers

[image: a)With Text]

[image: With Numbers]

2.Does not recognizes the number from seven segment display image

[image: Seven Segment Display image]

Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Unfortunately, at the moment the on-device model may not work well on 7 segment displays. I will take this as a feature request to our model team. Have you tried the on-cloud model?

Comment: @PannagSanketi What is the solution to read text from 7 segment image. Is there any other alternatives available. If Yes then guide me. I am also working on the same problem I want to read HB meter values using ML Kit.

Comment: @Srinivas Guni If you have the solution for this. plz, suggest me how I am able to achieve this.

Comment: I am also having the same problem.

Comment: @NivruttiPawar, I am also having the same problem with HB meter values. Have you got the solution regarding the same? Kindly post the answer if you have, it will help others.
Thank you.